# Touchscreen loses sensitivity until reboot?

Tags: touchscreen

I have an HP Spectre X360, using MATE.  I've noticed that the touchscreen loses sensitivity after a while, making it so that I actually have to press the screen harder for it to register a touch.  If I reboot, it goes back to normal.  Is there a way I can fix this, or at least reset the touchscreen driver so I don't have to keep rebooting?